# Get actual moint point of network volume in osx cli

Tags: macos, networking, volume, command-line-interface, mount-point

In an automated system, i copy files to a mounted network volume with a sh
In basic i do "cp file.pdf /Volumes/NetworkShare/".

This works well until the remote system is down. 
So before copying i can do a ping to detect if it's online.

But... when i get online OSX often remounts on a different path "/Volumes/NetworkShare-1/".
The old path "/Volumes/NetworkShare/" stil exists altough it's useless.

So, how can i find the actual mount point of this share in OSX cli?

I found out that diskutil does something like this for local disks, not for network volumes. Is there an equivalent for diskutil for network volumes?

Answer (score 0):

The `mount` command (just on its own) will list all mounted filesystems.  As for why OS X is creating that extra directory, that is pretty odd.  Did you manually mount the filesystem, by any chance?  If you created the “NetworkShare” directory yourself, OS X’s auto mounter might do what you’re suggesting.

Comment: This is also useful: http://superuser.com/questions/376914/how-to-list-network-shared-items-in-terminal